# C printing an array of two dimensions

Tags: c

In the following code, I am trying to read char by char from a file and store each char in a two dimensional array. After that I want to print each char in the array with its coordinates (i and j):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
int main(){

    char grid[3][5];
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    int c;

    if (file == NULL){
        perror("Error in reading the file");
    }
    else{
        int j=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {   
            while (j<5)
            {
                grid[i][j] = fgetc(file);
                j++;
            }
            j = 0;
        }
    }

    int length = sizeof grid / sizeof grid[0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            printf("%c %d %d \n", grid[i][j], i, j);

        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The file that I read from looks like:

```
ABCDE
FGHIJ
KLMNO
```

I want the result to be like:

```
A 0 0 
B 0 1
...
```

But the real results that I got is:

```
A 0 0
B 0 1
C 0 2
D 0 3
E 0 4

 1 0
F 1 1
G 1 2
H 1 3
I 1 4
J 2 0

 2 1
K 2 2
L 2 3
M 2 4
```

As you can see, the second row is printed with a space first and the same with the third row. Also, the last two letters N and O are not printed. Can someone help me solving this issue?

Comment: You are reading two `\n`'s as characters, which pushes the last two elements of your `char` array out.

Comment: Change the contents of your file to `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO` and it should work properly.

Answer (score 2):

Change this bit of code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{   
    while (j<5)
    {
         grid[i][j] = fgetc(file);
        j++;
    }
    j = 0;
}
```

To add in an if statement which will check to make sure the character it read in is not a newline character `\n`. The finished code will look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{   
    while (j<5)
    {
        char c = fegetc(file);
        if(c != '\n') 
        {
            grid[i][j] = fgetc(file);
            j++;
        }
    }
    j = 0;
}
```

Fiddling Bits suggested that the inner loop be changed to a for loop (for readability). I would agree, however it does have the drawback of having to put `j--` in the else part of the if statement, versus not even needing an else statement. You can view the above fix and this fix with the inner loop changed to a for loop, and decide which one you think has the best readability in this case. This code represents that change as well as the fix for the initial problem:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{   
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        char c = fegetc(file);
        if(c != '\n') 
        {
            grid[i][j] = fgetc(file);
        } else {
            j--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop would be cleaner too.

Comment: @FiddlingBits I agree. I'll edit the code to represent that. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add another fgetc(file); after the j=0;
(Without any assignment).
It will pull the new line char from your file